# WordPress - How to dynamically change language for the visitor

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like my visitors to be able to swich between languages with a language bar. I've tried to use Polylang but it totaly crashes my website, changing categories etc. (most likely because I've moved this site manually, without using Duplicator). Polylang seems to be confused and sometimes redirects users to the old address.

What I would like to do is to create a simple language bar that will set a language for the client and then will grab strings from .mo files to translate the content (not the content of posts, only selected, static content from the theme). I don't even know how to start, because all tutorials seem to be ignoring the explanation of how to switch between those languages. Those tutorials mention only how to add languages to WordPress.

Could anybody explain to me how to code this solution into my theme?

Answer (score 2):

WordPress does not support bilingual or multilingual sites really. Creating a mulitlingual WordPress site is basically installing WordPress in more than one language and creating a script to jump between them based on your users locality. However, you don't want to do this:

- If you install another 3rd part plugin, you will have to support translations.
- You may not be able to support the language, such as Liki (Moar), + the other hundreds.
- Making even the smallest of changes you could have a huge task on your hands.

You are best looking at the following approaches which are not PolyLang based lifted straight of the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress#Different_types_of_multilingual_plugins).

1. Manage multilingual posts in one post per language (e.g. WPML - paid, xili-language or Bogo). Translations are then linked together, indicating that one page is the translation of another.
   Store all languages alternatives for each post in the same post (e.g. qTranslate).
2. Manage translations on the generated page instead of using a post context (e.g. Transposh and Global Translator)
3. Plugins that direct you to external translation services (e.g. Google AJAX Translation)
4. Plugins like Multisite Language Switcher, Multilingual Press, and Zanto, link together separate
5. WordPress network (multisite) installations for each language by pinging back and forth.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, I've got to think about it really carefully. As soon as I make up my mind I will select this answer as correct.